# When are Haskell guard/ pattern matches considered none exhaustive?

Tags: haskell, conditional-statements, pattern-matching

I have the following code which defines a function called `merge`:

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] [] = []
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge x y | head x <= head y = x ++ y
          | head x > head y = y ++ x
merge x (y:ys) | head x <= y = x ++ merge [] (y:ys)
               | head x > y = y: merge x ys
merge (x:xs) y | x <= head y = x: merge xs y
               | x > head y = y ++ merge (x:xs) []
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) | x <= y = x : merge xs (y:ys)
                    | x > y = y : merge (x:xs) ys
```

This gives me the following warning:

```
Patterns not matched:
  [_] [_]
  [_] (_:_:_)
  (_:_:_) [_]
  (_:_:_) (_:_:_)
```

Looking at my code it's not clear to me what patterns I've missed. What extra patterns should I define to get rid of this warning?

As an aside, this is the same function but implemented with conditionals, this results in no warning. What is the difference between the pattern matched and guarded functions and the conditional function?

```
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = if x <= y then x : merge xs (y:ys) else y : merge (x:xs) ys
```

Comment: Floating point numbers do not always satisfy one of `x <= y` and `x > y`. Special values like NaNs make both comparisons false. Further, avoid using `head`: pattern matching is safe, while `head` can crash your program if called on an empty list. There's no need to use `head` here.

Comment: Okay, so how can I rewrite it to cover all possible cases?

Comment: You can avoid `head` as you did: `merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = ...` will give you access to the heads and match the "both non empty" case. To use guards on top of that, make sure the last guard is ` | otherwise ` (or ` | True`), as the answer below suggests. GHC knows about these two cases and will not emit warnings. Effectively, when generating warnings, GHC will only consider non-guarded patterns or patterns guarded by these two special guards. All other guards are seen by GHC as potentially false, and that can lead to warnings.

Comment: Instead of `merge x y | ...` then calling `head x`, write `merge xss@(x:xs) yss@(y:ys) | x <= y = xss ++ yss` -- i.e. `xss` on rhs refers to the whole list. But do you really want to concat those lists based only on comparing their heads? That contradicts the last 2 equations -- which is unreachable BTW. (And the first 2 equations duplicate.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler does not know that your guard conditions handle all the cases. Instead of

```
merge x y | head x <= head y = x ++ y
          | head x > head y  = y ++ x
```

you could use `True`

```
merge x y | head x <= head y = x ++ y
          | True             = y ++ x
```

or more idiomatic using `otherwise` (which is just another name for `True`):

```
merge x y | head x <= head y = x ++ y
          | otherwise        = y ++ x
```

Comment: Would making the change you suggested ensure every condition is covered?

Comment: Who said `True` was another name for `otherwise`? It is [`otherwise`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#otherwise).

Comment: @Connor: `otherwise` is an alias for `True`, not the other way.

Comment: In code-golf you frequently also see something like [`1<2`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25430/24877) instead of `otherwise`!

Comment: Another good option is `case head x <= head y of False -> ...; True -> ...` or similar. (Common variants include `if` instead of `case` and `compare`/`GT`/`_` instead of `<=`/`False`/`True`.)

Answer (score 2):

As explained, `head x <= head y` and `head x > head y` are not always each others opposite. Indeed, if we for example work with `NaN`, we see:

```
ghci> nan = 0 / 0
ghci> nan >= nan
False
ghci> nan < nan
False
```

so both fail. Likely your `head x > head y` should simply always succeed if the previous case fails. We can use `otherwise` for this, or `True`: a condition that is *always* true.

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | x <= y = …
    | otherwise = …
```

Here you need to rewrite the `…` parts. Using `x ++ y` and `y ++ x` was not sufficient: since we need to recurse on the (tail of the) lists and merge these as well.

Please do *not* use [**`head :: [a] -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:head) and [**`tail :: [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:tail): these are not *total*: for an empty list these will error. By making use of the pattern `(x:xs)` we here got a reference to the head `x` and the tail `xs` and the line will only "fire" if it is indeed a non-empty list.

Comment: Doesn't the function type `Ord => a` prevent `nan` being included?

Comment: @Conner: no, `Ord` only means that you can call `<`, `>=`, etc. on values of that type.

Comment: Okay, and `nan` falls into that category?

Comment: @Conner: `nan` has type `Double` (or `Float`) or another `Floating` type, `Double` and `Float` are instances of `Ord` yes.

Comment: Theoretically, `Ord` is supposed to represent a total order, and the presence of NaN values means that `Double` and `Float` are *not* total orders. Practically, it makes more sense to ignore NaN and treat the types as if they *were* total orders.